# Variable in bash via cron?

Tags: bash, cron

```
#!/bin/bash

ddd=$(date +%Y-%m -d "-1 month")
xmessage  -timeout 10 $ddd
```

If I try this simple script I get this to work fine from terminal but when I start this script via cron the variable is always empty? I have tried many different syntax but the result is the same. Work in Terminal but not from cron.

Comment: xmessage assumes an X-windows server to be running. Cron launches programs even without a controlling terminal.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to watch out for:

1. (as pointed out by @wildplasser), xmessage might not work from a cron environment - just check by running it with `"a test string"` instead of `$ddd`.
2. In many cron systems, the commands are executed with an empty environment, so that `$PATH` is empty. Just make sure to use absolute paths to the binaries (e.g. `/bin/date` and `/usr/bin/xmessage`).